# Restore deleted files

Tags: git, commit, restore

I had a lot of files in directory public/uploads/.  Before commit I typed `git rm -- public/uploads/*` and then `git commit -a -m "upload"` and then `git push origin master`. 
In previous commit photos are not present. Now I want to restore them back from git to server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You cannot recover them if they were never added or committed.</strike>

Let's say the hash of the commit where you deleted them is abc123. If you want to undo the whole commit, simply do `git revert abc123`. If there were other parts of the commit you want to keep, do:

```
git revert abc123 --no-commit
git reset
git add public/uploads/
git commit
```

Then the files will be back in the repository.

Comment: but they are present via bitbucket when i see commit details, photos are still loading as `deleted`

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood your question then. Were they ever committed?

Comment: Assuming you have committed them at least once, I have edited the answer to reflect the solution.